# Looking for asp.net 3D surface charts

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need something to create 3D surface charts in ASP.Net. Could anyone recommend a 3rd party component set? I also do not want to use Giga Soft's, Nevron's, or ComponentOne's components. I am open to non-free solutions.

Comment: Are you willing to pay for a third party solution?  I haven't had any success finding a good, free 3d surface visualization API.

Comment: yep, i dont mind if its not free. as long as its fast 3D surface charts

Answer (score 3):

This is a good question.
I have performed a search/watch for my company few months ago and it is a cruel lack.
Personnaly I would not go for expensive third party solutions as they are seriously overpriced IMHO. Most of them do not give enough interactivity and are full of flourish while lacking the real features that one could expect from a decent 3D Surface.

I've ended up using [ILNumerics](http://ilnumerics.net) which is fully open source (and even contributed a bit to the project). It's Winforms, but you could port it to ASP by tweaking a bit. 
Snapshots [Here](http://ilnumerics.net/%24VisualExamples.html)

Comment: @Haymo Kutschbach : Thx 4Fixing broken Links

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `Dundas Charting`  because of its stability and easy to use system

It provide different kinds of charts and work great with / without SQL Server Reporting Services, it has dynamic and static reports so that you user can build his report on the fly with your current reports.

Comment: This is my personal opinion, but This is way, way overfeatured and overpriced. the OP only needs a 3D chart. You don't buy a castle when you need a hotel room.

Comment: Dundas chart cannot visualize 3D surface charts at all so even if the price was right, it does not fit this job...